# How to share my private key Nativescript simple libsodium

Tags: angular, cryptography, nativescript, libsodium

I'm starting a nativescript project with [Simple libsodium NativeScript](https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-simple-libsodium) plugin, but I am not sure how to reconstruct my public key once I shared it as string. I'm doing this:

```
 KeyToString(){

  let my = this.simpleLibsodium.boxKeyPaired();

  // Convert publicKey in to string
  let stringBase64 = this.simpleLibsodium.bytesToBase64(my.public_key) // "ABDCDFDAB2ABD2BBACDFDC"

  // Here there is not problem!!!
  return stringBase64

}


StringToKey(base64String){

  // I WANT TO CONVERT FROM BASE64 STRING TO PUBLIC KEY AGAIN
  ???
}
```

I'm not sure that this is even possible, but if it is I will appreciate any help since this plugin documentation is very limited and the original libsodium docs does not translate quite well to this library.

Comment: Um... `base64ToBytes()`?

Comment: The documentation states `base64Tobytes()` shall be used, did you try it? Are you facing any issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some try i realized i was doing something really dumb, 
i only was converting the public key to string when you need both keys to decrytp the message usin crypto_box_easy()

Thanks